# Getting reference to helper in $A.getCallback()

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm making a cometd call in $A.getCallback() so that I have access to the component outside of the regular render lifecycle. This works well, but I need access to a Helper method belonging to that component. Is there any way to get this?

```
$.cometd.subscribe('/topic/myTopic', $A.getCallback(function(message){
    //cmp is in scope because of getCallback()
    if (cmp.isValid()) {
     // here's what I'd like to do
     helper.myFunction();
    }
}));
```

Edit: The code is already in the Helper. If it were in the Controller then I can get access to the Helper. Normally when calling a Helper method from another Helper method, I'd use `this` but that doesn't work in this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The helper can call other methods within itself via `this`. You need to create a reference to `this` in order to use it within the callback; traditionally this is called `self`, but it can be whatever makes sense to you. Using this method creates a closure to give you access to the helper.

```
helperMethod: function(cmp) {
    var self = this;
    $.cometd.subscribe('/topic/myTopic', $A.getCallback(function(message){
        //cmp is in scope because of getCallback()
        if (cmp.isValid()) {
            // here's what I'd like to do
            self.myMethod();
       }
    }));
},
myMethod: function(...) {
    // Do something here
}
```

Comment: Indeed it does, I should have clarified; my cometd callout is already in the Helper - perhaps it should not be? Updated my question but otherwise I'll move the callout to the Controller which will solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @MattChinnock Oh, give me a moment to edit, then.